# Ansible Jinja2 issue iterating over a list when inventory_hostname is top of variable tree

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I am facing an issue with Jinja2 iterating over list list when inventory_hostname is at the top of variable tree.

My YAML (group_vars/all/main.yaml):

```
router1:
  interfaces:
  - { name: ge-0/0/0, ipv4_address: 192.168.0.11, ipv4_mask: '24' }
  - { name: ge-0/0/1, ipv4_address: 192.168.1.11, ipv4_mask: '24' }
router2:
  interfaces:
  - { name: ge-0/0/0, ipv4_address: 192.168.0.12, ipv4_mask: '24' }
  - { name: ge-0/0/1, ipv4_address: 192.168.1.12, ipv4_mask: '24' }
```

The following Jinja2 template fails:

```
{% for interface in [inventory_hostname].interfaces %}
interface {{ interface.name }}
   ...
!
{% endfor %}
```

And I don't see why?

I managed to get it working with the following but it looks ugly:

```
{% for interface in hostvars[inventory_hostname][inventory_hostname].interfaces %}
interface {{ interface.name }}
   ...
!
{% endfor %}
```

Why is the first template not working?

Comment: The content you've labelled "My YAML"...where is it? Is it part of your playbook? Part of your inventory? A variable file in `group_vars`?

Comment: I am using a single variable file: group_vars/all/main.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is invalid:

```
{% for interface in [inventory_hostname].interfaces %}
```

You use brackets like `[...]`...

- To index a list, like `my_var[0]` or `my_var[1]`
- To access a dictionary value, like `my_var['name']` or `my_var['size']`
- To create a list, like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

But you can't use them the way you're trying to use them.

---

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem. I think the most elegant solution would be to move the settings out of `group_vars/all`, and instead create:

- `host_vars/router1.yml` with the following content:

  ```
  interfaces:
  - { name: ge-0/0/0, ipv4_address: 192.168.0.11, ipv4_mask: '24' }
  - { name: ge-0/0/1, ipv4_address: 192.168.1.11, ipv4_mask: '24' }
  ```
- `host_vars/router2.yml` with the following content:

  ```
  interfaces:
  - { name: ge-0/0/0, ipv4_address: 192.168.0.12, ipv4_mask: '24' }
  - { name: ge-0/0/1, ipv4_address: 192.168.1.12, ipv4_mask: '24' }
  ```

With this in place, your template simply becomes:

```
{% for interface in interfaces %}
```

And it will use the correct value for whichever host the task is currently targeting.

---

If you really need to keep your current configuration, you can use the `vars` lookup, like this:

```
{% for interface in lookup('vars', inventory_hostname).interfaces %}
```

...but I really think you would find things more manageable if you restructure your data.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution to have two parameters files, one for each group :

(group_vars/router1.yaml):

```
interfaces:
- { name: ge-0/0/0, ipv4_address: 192.168.0.11, ipv4_mask: '24' }
- { name: ge-0/0/1, ipv4_address: 192.168.1.11, ipv4_mask: '24' }
```

(group_vars/router2.yaml):

```
interfaces:
- { name: ge-0/0/0, ipv4_address: 192.168.0.12, ipv4_mask: '24' }
- { name: ge-0/0/1, ipv4_address: 192.168.1.12, ipv4_mask: '24' }
```

And to use them like following example in your jinja2 templates :

```
{% for interface in interfaces %}
interface {{ interface.name }}
   ...
!
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to keep all my parameters in a single file (group_vars/all/main.yaml).